# Masking external links with internal link for member-only

Tags: php, functions, membership

I'd like to know how I should implement this code, to filter URLs for members and non-members? Should I put the code into the `functions.php` file?

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if( $user->exists ) {
    add_filter( 'public_link_root', function() { return 'example.com'; });
}

// Whenever you have to output a link, instead of doing that check over and over, because it's already established that the user's logged in, if you wrote your system in the correct manner (and you can do additional checks), do:

$link_to_output = apply_filters( 'public_link_root', 'ourwebsite.com' ) . '/resources/whatever/here';
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add the hook function in your functions.php file:

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if($user->exists) {
    add_filter('public_link_root', function() { return 'example.com'; } );
}
```

Then whenever you are working with a URL in any of your template files, you can allow the URL to be modified by your customer filter `public_link_root`. The filter will only run if the user exists, otherwise the URL won't be altered.

So in your template files:

```
$some_link = apply_filters('public_link_root', 'ourwebsite.com') . '/resources';
echo '<a href="' . $some_link . '">View Resources</a>';
```

For this to make more sense, you should spend some time reading the documentation and example code on [add_filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) and [apply_filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/).

Comment: thanks but is this really changes all external link structure in every posts and the user cannot access download link unless they logged in? have u tested?

Comment: It's hard to know what you want it to do as your question isn't very clear. If you don't want to alter links on all posts, then only add the code to specific templates or to the specific links you want to change.

Comment: tried those codes in functions.php and single post php but nothing changes nothing happens

Comment: Can you show your code? Also, you can use `echo` and `die` statements to check that your hook is being called. Do you have `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` for development, and do you have anything in your error.log file?

Comment: i've used the above code.

Comment: You said you don't know where to put that code?! I'm asking what files you have added it to, and to show a bit more of the code so that we can help...

Comment: functions.php and single.php but as i said it should mask links for logged-in members as well and logged out members shouldn't be able to access if they paste into their browser.

Comment: Ok, so again show the code you are using in the `single.php` file and `functions.php`, exactly as it appears. The users copying a URL into their browser is a separate issue and requires some checking on the template to redirect user who are not members.

Comment: i've used your above code, first one for functions.php and the 2nd for single.php

Comment: I need to see the context - if you have literally just copied and pasted my code then it's not going to work as you need to apply it to your specific project. If you can't help people who are trying to answer your question then you're going to struggle on this site!

Comment: now i see, i don't have proper coding skills to change your code